# hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto не создает таблицу

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate, crud

Пишу свое первое CRUD приложение на голом спринге без бута. Столкнулся с тем, что не создаются таблицы через entity. Сконфигурировал вроде все верно. Единственные решения, которые мне попались - использовать spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto. Но на данный момент мне это не нужно

**db.properties**

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8080/dbName

jdbc.username=user
jdbc.password=password

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

**EntityManagerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:db.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "userEditor")

public class EntityManagerConfig {
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    public void setEnv(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProps() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("userEditor.model");
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(hibernateProps());
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }

}
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userinfo", schema = "public")

public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Role> role;

    public User() {
    }

    + констуркторы, сеттеры, геттеры
```

Comment: Покажите где вы их создаёте. Какая ошибка?